# Creating a secure MSSQL login with limited permissions

Tags: php, sql-server, security, authentication

I've built a web form using PHP which takes a user's basic details and inserts them into a MSSQL table. This web form is going to be used on the company's external website and used by a wide variety of people.

This being the case I assume I would need to create a login using SQL Server Authentication, correct?

I wrote a quick script to set up a new login and user for the database and give it only the ability to INSERT data from the web form.

```
CREATE LOGIN TESTWeb WITH PASSWORD = 'monkey'
USE companydb
CREATE USER memaw FOR LOGIN TESTWeb
GRANT INSERT TO memaw
Go
```

Obviously these are fudged details. :)

Is this going to be secure enough? The way I understand it is that this would give the login TESTWeb the ability to only insert data into the database 'companydb', and nothing else.

Also, I'm a bit fuzzy on the implications of connecting to MSSQL through a PHP script and how secure it is.

```
<?php

 $server = 'site_man';
 $user = 'TESTWeb';
 $pass = 'monkey';

 $con = mssql_connect($server, $user, $pass);

 //rest of script
?>
```

Is having this at the top of your PHP script secure enough or should this detail be stored elsewhere and called using an INCLUDE?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

PHP files are executed server side. This means that the viewers cannot see the code, and even with a severly restricted account, PHP is extremely secure. However, you do have to make sure you protect yourself from XSS (cross site scripting).

http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/509-Protect-Data-From-Cross-Site-Scripting-XSS-Attacks

It doesn't matter whether you place the data in on the top of the PHP script or include it with a separate PHP script. However, if you are going to be connecting to the database on more than one different script, including will make it easier if you ever have to change any of the details, as you just have to change one file then.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought.

Any thoughts about the MSSQL issue?